# Python Numpy Matrix Update Confusion

Tags: numpy, matrix, sparse-matrix, matrix-factorization

this is a part of my matrix factorization code (a very weird version of nmf). My issue is that although every time when I iterate, I save the older copies of the W and H matrices, when I compare old_W and W after W finishes updating every time, they are actually the same! So the actual error output is always 0 and the while loop stops after the first iteration. However, "#print old - new" shows that the element W[r][i] is actually updated every time. What is it that I am not seeing?

```
def csmf(V, l, max_iter, err, alpha=0.01, beta=0.01, lamb=0.01):
  W = np.random.rand(V.shape[0], l)
  H = np.random.rand(l, V.shape[1])
  n = V.shape[0]
  N = V.shape[1]

  NwOone = 60
  NwOtwo = 60
  NhOone = 50
  NhOtwo = 50

  for t in range(max_iter):
    old_W = W # save old values
    old_H = H
    old = criterion(V,old_W,old_H,l,alpha,beta,lamb)
    print "iteration ", t

    ##### update W
    print "updating W"
    setw = range(0,n)
    subset_one = random.sample(setw,NwOone)
    subset_two = calcGw(V, W, H, n, l, alpha, beta, NwOtwo)
    chosen = np.intersect1d(subset_one,subset_two)

    for r in chosen:
      for i in range(len(W[0])):
        update = wPosNeg(W[r],N,i,l,V,r,beta,H)
        old = W[r][i]
        W[r][i] = update
        new = W[r][i]
        #print old - new

    ##### update H
    print "updating H"
    seth = range(0,N)
    subset_oneh = random.sample(seth,NhOone)
    subset_twoh = calcGh(V, W, H, N, l, NhOtwo,lamb)
    chosenh = np.intersect1d(subset_oneh,subset_twoh)

    for s in chosenh: # column
      for i in range(len(H)):
        updateh = hPosNeg(H[i],n,i,l,V,s,lamb,W)
        H[i][s] = updateh

    ##### check err
    print "Checking criterion"
    print criterion(V,W,H,l,alpha,beta,lamb)
    print criterion(V,old_W,old_H,l,alpha,beta,lamb)
    actual = abs(criterion(V,W,H,l,alpha,beta,lamb)  -criterion(V,old_W,old_H,l,alpha,beta,lamb))
    if actual <= err: return W, H, actual
  return W, H, actual

dmat = np.random.rand(100,80)
W, H, err = csmf(dmat, 1, 10, 0.001, alpha=0.001, beta=0.001, lamb=0.001)
print err
```

Comment: By the way, the criterion() function definitely works and output different error values when I use different W and H matrices.

Comment: `w[r][I]=...` looks suspicious.  `w[r,I]=...` is better.

Comment: w[r][i] also works. My real problem was that I wasn't making the copies in the right way. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Sometimes (but not always) `W[r]` is a copy, not a view.  In that case `W[r][i]=...` doesn't change `W`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in these lines:

    `old_W = W # save old values
    old_H = H`

you are not saving a copy, you are keeping a reference (old_W and W are the same piece of memory).

Try this:

    `old_W = W.copy() # save old values
    old_H = H.copy()`

Comment: Hi! Yes this was indeed the error! Thank you so much!

Comment: great, please accept the answer to close the question.